# Android unit test are failing with initializationError if RunWith RobolectricTestRunner

Tags: android, junit4, java-11, robolectric, android-api-31

My Android unit test is failing with initializationError if RunWith RobolectricTestRunner.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) // If I use @RunWith(Junit4.class) it works
@Config(application = Application.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {


    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
        assertEquals("actualMessage", "expectedErrorMessage");
    }
}
```

Here is the entire stacktrace:

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type [unknown] not present
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:682)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:267)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3757)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3746)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3651)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:213)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Application
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:674)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.Application
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 31 more
```

testImplementation in build.gradle for robolectric is 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.8.1'

jdk version 11

api level 31

gradle version 4.10.1

android studio ChipMunk

Please help! Thank You!